# Building Anjay tutorial codes

Tags: c, cmake

I'm getting some difficulties on building the tutorial codes of Anjay https://github.com/AVSystem/Anjay. the doc wasn't really helpful.

I tried a simple :

```
cd examples/tutorial/custom-object
cmake . && make
```

but I'm getting this message :

```
By not providing "Findanjay.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "anjay", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "anjay" with any of
  the following names:

    anjayConfig.cmake
    anjay-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "anjay" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "anjay_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "anjay"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I would appreciate any suggetions.
Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can see you need to build the top level project. Run `cmake -S . -B build` from the top level Anjay directory. The examples directory is not meant to be built separately. When in doubt about supported options use a `cmake -L .` from the build directory.

Comment: Hi @vre, thanks for the answer,I tried it but it's still not working, in the output file I find only the demo exe.

Comment: Sorry it worked, that was my bad. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was doing the same thing. The error is because you have not installed anjay libraries on your local system or provide a way for CMake to find it.
I installed it by following steps mentioned in [compilation docs](https://avsystem.github.io/Anjay-doc/Compiling_client_applications.html)

In the root of Anjay directory execute the following:

```
cmake . && make && sudo make install
```